# Wrong sorting with Collator using Locale.TRADITIONAL_CHINESE

Tags: java, android, collator

I want to order the list by Chinese text strokes count and I am using the method to create Collator to achieve it but it seems the Collator with TRADITIONAL_CHINESE have some error.

for the example,

```
 List<String> strList = new List<>();
 strList.add("日");
 strList.add("蘋");
 Collections.sort(strList, new SortChinese());




 class SortChinese implements Comparator<String> {

        public int compare(String obj1, String obj2) {

            Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(Locale.TRADITIONAL_CHINESE);
            collator.setStrength(Collator.PRIMARY);
            return collator.compare(obj1, obj2);

        }
    }
```

before: 日,蘋

after: 蘋,日

expected result : 日,蘋

Any idea or suggestion for Chinese strokes count Sorting in android?

Comment: Try using `SECONDARY` or `TERTIARY` for the strength. The stroke count might not be considered as a primary difference.

Comment: tried before, and the result is same as Collator.PRIMARY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove ShortChinese:

```
List<String> strList = new List<>();
strList.add("日");
strList.add("蘋"); 

Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(Locale.TRADITIONAL_CHINESE);
collator.setStrength(Collator.PRIMARY);
Collections.sort(strList, collator);
```

Comment: still not work, Is it the problem about the jre version?
my android version is 2.3.3, jre version 1.8.0_112-release-06

Comment: I think I know what problem it is.
tested code on the real android device and it is work but tested the code on the android studio default emulator, the result will get wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
strList.sort((o1, o2) -> compareInChinese(str1, str2));
```

Maybe you can add this to your util class.

```
public static int compareInChinese(String str1, String str2) {
    Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(new Locale("zh", "CN"));
    collator.setDecomposition(Collator.NO_DECOMPOSITION);
    collator.setStrength(Collator.PRIMARY);
    return collator.compare(str1, str2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code of @propoLis works for me (Java 8, Windows). Edited and compiled with UTF-8. Maybe you edited with an other encoding than it was compiled.

So try instead:

```
strList.add(new String(new int[] {0x65e5}, 0, 1)); // Unicode code points
strList.add(new String(new int[] {0x860b}, 0, 1));
```

Or

```
strList.add("\u65e5"); // Unicode UTF-16
strList.add("\u860b");
```

*However you would need 2 errors to receive Chinese again.*

Comment: I am using the android studio UTF-8 encoding and tested your code but still got the wrong result